# "code that is not properly formatted" for reference-style link

Tags: support, editor, quality-filter

[My answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24755558/measure-elapsed-time-in-swift#37450692) gets this error when I try to edit it. The root of this error is the reference-style link; removing the links eliminates the error.

Comment: I had no trouble editing it... I suppose that means the check is not done after a certain reputation threshold?

Comment: @CodyGray That is probably the case. I though only administrators can ignore the error.

Comment: "code that is not properly formatted" that's quite funny for your answer, because it is very well formatted. Good job :).

Comment: @Tom Thank you. The Markdown source may seems odd though, because I set it to monospace in order to left-align the ordered/unordered list (personal weird taste). Also the bug seems to have been fixed, since I managed to update it just now. Yay! Should I label it as [tag:status-completed], or I should wait for an admin to confirm that?

Comment: Only moderators can add the special [status-*] tags, so you can't actually add that. If you want, you can answer your own question, explaining that this has been fixed, and when the system allows you to, accept your own answer. But you don't have to. Developers periodically go through all the questions tagged [bug] and triage them.